# Hibernate. Convert HQL to Criteria API

Tags: nhibernate, hql, criteria

How to convert the following hql to Criteria API

```
var criteria = this.Session.CreateQuery("select m, m.Attachments.size from AdvanceMessage m");
```

?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit vague but it's something like this :

```
IList<AdvanceMessage> list = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(AdvanceMessage))
    .List<AdvanceMessage>();
```

Comment: This return only all fields from AdvanceMessages table. But the first one, I asked, generate a T-SQL statement like:  

SELECT m.*, COUNT(SELECTf.Id FROM MessageAttachment f WHERE f.messageId = m.messageId) FROM AdvanceMessages m


I found a solution which is to create a criteria type of AdvanceMessage and add GroupProperty projection for this class fields and also to add an additional subquery projection with a RowNumber Projection inside.